# React native: How to prevent memory leak caused by updating state on unmounted component.State is updated after receiving an api response?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios, redux-saga

Is the solution below actually preventing memory leaks on the react-native App or just hiding the warning?

Is there any other solution for fixing this issue other than the solution below.

I found a way to prevent the state update on API response. By using useRef like below

```
const _isMounted = useRef(true); // Initial value _isMounted = true
  
useEffect(() => {
       _isMounted.current = true;
       return () => {
           _isMounted.current = false;
       }
}, []);

const onResponse = () => {
  if (_isMounted.current) {
     setResponse(data);
  }
}
```

Is there any other solution for fixing this issue? I use redux-saga to handle API.

In redux-saga, I pass a callback. The code gives me a warning state is updated after unmounting

```
 const [isSubmitting, setSubmitting] = useState(false); // this state is used to disable submit button and show loader

 props.saveData({
    token: props.login_token,
    setSubmitting: setSubmitting,
    data: data 
 });
```

Solution

```
 props.saveData({
    token: props.login_token,
    setSubmitting: (flag)=>{
                        if(_isMounted.current){
                            setSubmitting(flag);
                        }
                    },
    data: data
     });
```

Another solution I found was to cancel Axios but I don't want to cancel a POST operation.

Comment: Can you just store the state in redux?

Comment: Nope I have a list of cards on which there is button to update status .

Comment: So you're *only* using `redux-saga` to make a request to the api, but not to manage the state surrounding that action?

Comment: To make request and store the result in reducer.The are multiple component with same action.Since it's displayed in a list.

Comment: if I set a state in redux to handle this action, then all component associated with this action will respond to that state.For eg changing state of a button, On enabled and submitting(disables the button and show loader)